# why my method of localization in react native always go to else block?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I pass "ar" but function always going to else part

```
const _retrieveData = async () => {
  console.log('_retrieveData')
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LocalizationKey');
    const result = JSON.stringify(value);
    console.log("result==>type", typeof (result))
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log('value--------> in getItem', value)
      if (result === "ar") {
        console.log('i18local__ar')
        I18n.locale = "ar";
      }
      else {
        console.log('i18local__en')
        I18n.locale = "en";
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error)
  }
}
```

console show when I call the function with pass "ar" as an argument

result ==> type string

i18.js:16 value --------> in getItem "ar"

PLEASE help me to solve this problem
Thank you!!!

Comment: There must be something else going on, going by the information you have submitted in the question, there's no reason for the code to proceed to else part, If possible console log the result of expression in if, check their types etc to see if they're really equal or maybe you have a extra character in result, most probably a space character

Comment: you log value but compare result, and it could be that result really inculudes the quotes, say is `"ar"` instead of `ar`

Answer (score 0):

I am closing my issue because it is resolved now .
I am comparing the "ar" with ar that the problem both is of string type that's why they show me the type string